# Does AWS charge for SSL certificate if I have a Free AWS Tier Account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I need a Google Gmail login on my web page. For that Google API console asking me for an SSL Certificate linked to my website. So I'm searching for a free SSL certificate from AWS. Does AWS charge for an SSL certificate if I have a Free AWS Tier Account?

https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

Comment: As the page says, you need "Elastic Load Balancers, Amazon CloudFront distributions, and APIs on API Gateway" to use the certificate manager.  If you have a simple EC2 you can't use that but you can use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)

Comment: posted a solution which tells about pricing and billing related to acm and with which services it can be used, does it help?

Answer (score 5):

*[Public SSL/TLS certificates provisioned through AWS Certificate Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html) are free. You pay only for the AWS resources you create to run your application.*[source](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/)

*You pay a one-time fee for private certificates for which you have access to the private key. This fee is incurred in the AWS account from which you issue the certificate. For certificates you issue directly from a standalone Private CA, you are charged when you issue a certificate.*

for public certicates its free for privates yes.
for more details https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=5#Billing, https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/pricing/?nc=sn&loc=3